# Jquery Counter with Background color Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Counter that counts from 0 to a specified number - and this works perfect I think.
As the number increments up, the background color of a div height should also animate upwards to that percentage of the counter.

So 50% Counter should animate the green background 50 % of the div height also- all both in sync at the same time and the same speed, stopping and starting at the same time.

I have my fiddle code here- but I know its not working perfectly and the code is a bit separated.
http://jsfiddle.net/QGNKt/3/

Can someone guide me to clean this up a bit? am i on the write track?. 
A help hand on touching up the JSFiddle code will be helpful.
I know i can get it working with the code I have no- but the code seems to separated- MAYBE what i have now will do - lol

```
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        #container {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
        }

        #green {
            height: 500px;
            width: 50px;
            background: #090;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function () {
            function createCounter(elementId, start, end, totalTime, callback) {
                var jTarget = jQuery("#" + elementId);
                var interval = totalTime / (end - start);
                var intervalId;
                var current = start;
                var f = function () {
                    jTarget.text(current);
                    if (current == end) {
                        clearInterval(intervalId);
                        if (callback) {
                            callback();
                        }
                    }
                    ++current;
                }
                intervalId = setInterval(f, interval);
                f();
            }
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                createCounter("counterTarget", 0, 50, 2000, function () {
                    //alert("finished")
                })
            })
            //]]>

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#green').animate({
                    top: 30
                }, 2300, function () {
                    //$('#button').val('down');
                });
            });
        });//]]>  

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="font-size: 135px" id="counterTarget"></h1>
    <h1 class="f-l">%</h1>

    <div id="container" style="border: Red solid 1px;">
        <div id="green"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QGNKt/4/) =

Comment: Yea Thank this was much cleaner- Thanks for cleaning up it up- I appreciate it- Not i can just set my height in the CSS and then change my percentage in  $('#green').animate({
         height: '50%'

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted out your code and tidied it up a bit. Have you tried using a pre made solution for progress bars and the likes? Have a look at [`Twitter Bootstrap`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/QGNKt/6/

Comment: +1, guess I'll have to upvote, even if it took you ten minutes to steal the code in my fiddle.

Comment: @adeneo Nope. I started on the fiddle before you had even commented (Look at the revisions), but +1 for your answer too :)

Comment: @user1214467 I forgot to mention as well, but the TidyUp feature in jsFiddle is really helpful when it comes to trying to sort out code that is mis-indented etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot appreciate it.

Comment: @lEwis can we speak privately?

Comment: @user1214467 Please keep comments related to the question/answer. All discussions should be taken to the Chat and are welcome there.